# Type 'typeof import("...")' does not satisfy the constraint 'IEntry'

Tags: typescript, next.js

When I am building my NextJS 13 app using `npm run build`, I am receiving the following type error:

```
Type error: Type 'typeof import("E:/myapp/app/login/page")' does not satisfy the constraint 'IEntry'.
  Types of property 'default' are incompatible.
    Type 'typeof Login' is not assignable to type 'PageComponent'.
      Type 'typeof Login' provides no match for the signature '(props: PageProps): ReactNode | Promise<ReactNode>'.
```

Here is the simplified definition of the `Login` class mentioned above:

```
class Login extends React.Component<{}, {data: any}>{

    constructor(props: any){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: null;
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        //some logic
    }

    render(){
        return <h1>Hello World</h1>
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me understand why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest an approach as below:

```
constructor<T extends PageProps>(props: T){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: null;
    }
}
```

I suppose constructor of superclass expects parameters of PageProps type.